# How to have a Python Script run 24/7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a python script called post.py that checks for HTTP "POST" methods to my server. This is all being held on an AWS EC2 instance. I want it so that the service is constantly running this python script and that I don't have to open a command line prompt and run: `python post.py`

How do you set up a python script like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to daemonize my script very easily:

I went to /etc/init/ and added a file called post.config.

I put in this:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env AN_ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLE=i-want-to-set

respawn

exec /home/ubuntu/Files/mysite/post.py
```

And now it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to daemonize your script. Your config file should look something like this:

```
[program:post]
command: /usr/bin/python -m post
directory: /home/ubuntu/post  # if post.py is in a folder called post that lives in home/ubuntu
autostart: true
```

Comment: Will this make it so that the script is constantly running?

Comment: Yes, I have used this method to deploy web applications.

Comment: How do I get supervisord to run the code you posted?

Comment: You install supervisor via `apt-get` and when you place the config file in it's proper place and restart supervisor it will take it from there

Comment: How do you restart supervisor, I've gotten everything else

Comment: `sudo supervisorctl restart` or `sudo supervisorctl stop/start`

Comment: When I restart supervisor it says post stopped, post started, but it does not actually work - the server is not receiving files. When I run python post.py I still get files.

Comment: You should probably open a new question for supervisor if that is the case. This one has gotten a little long.

Comment: Can you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141663/supervisord-wont-start-script-returns-error-abnormal-termination

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to detach the execution from terminal you can use nohup(http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html) for that,else if you wanted to execute the post.py more than once in a scheduled fashion. you can use cron job for this - linux utilty.If you want to do this in python you can check this out https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Comment: I don't want to execute multiple times, just once and then have the script not cancel when I exit terminal.

Comment: Will you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141663/supervisord-wont-start-script-returns-error-abnormal-termination

Comment: yes you can use nohup for that. `nohup command[blah blah] &`.